# asp.net website full text search with ravendb and lucene

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, lucene, ravendb

I am using ravendb for my intranet website. I need to implement full text search on whole website ? I can use ravendb's linq search queries for documents which is lucene based in the background.

Other approach is to use Lucene.Net library to implement fulltext search independently.

Whatever approach I choose, it should be able to search through attachments stored in blob format in ravendb.

Any ideas or suggestions please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RavenDB is fully integrated with Lucene.  There would be little point to using it independently.

But by definition, attachments are not searchable.  You can certainly store very large documents that are fully searchable, but they wouldn't be attachments.  The whole point of attachments are for things that you wouldn't *want* to search.  Example: videos, photos, music, etc.

Review:

- http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/attachments
- http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/linq-extensions/search
- http://ravendb.net/docs/appendixes/lucene-indexes-usage

**Revised Answer**

I have written a bundle that uses [IFilters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFilter) to have RavenDB automatically extract the contents of attachments and index them with Lucene.  [It is available here](https://github.com/mj1856/RavenDB-IndexedAttachments).

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks much for your help. But how to do full text search for doc and pdf document attachments uploaded by users and stored in ravendb ?

Comment: You'll need to extract the searchable text from the document first.  Raven can't do this for you.  See https://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/66b0fc780a02534e

Comment: Thanks Matt for your quick reply. So even users who use Lucene.net independently would do the same for searching the pdf or word documents ? Or is there any standard approach if using Lucene.net ? In that case we need to handle for different formats like .txt, .doc, .docx, .pdf. And in the link you gave, it has only pdf extraction but what about word doc or other formats ? I need to look for third party library for each format ?

Comment: I've never done this, but a quick search yielded the following that are worth a look: [1](http://kalanir.blogspot.com/2008/08/indexing-pdf-documents-with-lucene.html)  [2](http://poi.apache.org/)  [3](http://npoi.codeplex.com/)

Comment: There's also [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) which is mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/3f671386c01275b0) and [here](https://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/e32583df74f31250)  but I don't know of anyone that has done this yet.  If you are successful, please share your results! :)

Comment: Also, check out [this post](http://kevm.github.com/tikaondotnet/) for how to run Tika on .Net

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help :) I will try Tika.

Comment: FYI - you've inspired me.  I'm starting a bundle for the [raven.contrib](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb.contrib) project that will address this concern.  I'm leaning towards using iFilters instead of Tika, mainly due to the IKVM dependency.  Keep an eye out on the ravendb google group for an announcement in the next week or so.